# react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6

Tags: react-native, dependencies

I want to create an app available on Android and iOS. I have a background using Android Studio but I am new with cross-platform development.

I just install node.js v10.15.0npm.
I also installed Atom and Nuclide.
I put `install -g create-react-native-app` in my terminal and I create my first app Dimitest  : `create-react-native-app Dimitest`.
I choosed `expo-template-blank` for my template.
But then several warnings appear and I really do not know how to fix them.

Can someone help me ?

> - npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer
>     dependencies yourself.
> - npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer
>     dependencies yourself.
> - npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
> - npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Then I tried `npm start` and this then appeared:

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\melis\Documents\Projet_react_dimi\package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open npm
>   ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\melis\Documents\Projet_react_dimi\package.json' npm ERR!
>
> enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR!
>
> enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\melis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-28T16_35_44_491Z-debug.log